# Skin effect in a 2D conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conductors

We know that the skin effect is the tendency of current to flow mainly near the surface of a conductor that happens when it is driven by a time-varying current. This situation is usually explained in case of a cylindrical conductor, like that shown in the following picture at left.

[image]

But in some situations, our conductor is so thin to be approximated as a foil (2D), for instance in case of strip lines, patches etc. Let's consider a rectangular foil as that shown in the picture at the middle. Since it's a foil, it does not have (ideally) a cross-section. Will the AC current flow uniformly along all the area of the foil, or in this case does the skin mean that AC  current will flow in the edges of the foil (which are segments)?

I'd say that current will flow uniformly on all the area of the foil. But someone told me that in this case, the current on the edges is  more important.

Picture taken from [here](https://arunashok.com/electrical/f/what-is-electrical-skin-effect-in-power-system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you suggest, edge current density is greater than center-of-foil current density.

Skin effect comes from the magnetic field that a current generates, and
which impinges on adjacent conductive material.   Conductive materials
are often diamagnetic (resist the penetration of magnetic field) and
at high AC frequencies, are very much diamagnetic.

The magnetic field generated by an edge-of-foil current only impinges on
adjacent metal on ONE
SIDE of the current, while the magnetic field generated by a center-of-foil
current impinges on two sides.   The foil-center current is lessened
by this, because the magnetic field generates an opposing electromotive
force.   It isn't as simple as a 'skin depth' situation, because the
highly symmetric effect on a cylinder conductor can be approximated
easily, while the strip of foil has no such symmetry.